# Why is my array-merge printing everything but the last row in my index?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script that cycles through a folder pathway and combined a bunch of single reports into a master report, and then it prints the whole compiled set of arrays onto a master worksheet. It's working well, printing after the header row, but it's printing the array up until the last row of data from the last compiled report. There are 148 rows in the arrays index, but it only prints 147 of them and exits out of the sub.

Here's the area where I make a second array to print it at once, maybe somewhere in here is cutting it off?

```
ReDim varArray2(1 To UBound(varArray, 2), 1 To UBound(varArray, 1))

With Workbooks("Retail_Goal_Report.xlsm").Worksheets("Merged Reports")

    For j = 1 To UBound(varArray, 2)
        For k = 1 To UBound(varArray, 1)
            varArray2(j, k) = varArray(k, j)
        Next
    Next

    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(UBound(varArray, 2), UBound(varArray, 1))) = varArray2
End With
```

Whole code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Sharepoint_Merge()


Dim k As Long, x As Long, j As Long ' counters
Dim varArray() As Variant
Dim varArray2() As Variant
ReDim varArray(1 To 23, 1 To 1)
Dim folderPath As String, filepath As String, filename As String
Dim wb As Workbook

Dim myvar As Variant
Dim myFolder As String
Dim i As Long

folderPath = "C:\merge\"

filepath = folderPath & "*.xlsx"

filename = Dir(filepath)

Call Ludicrous(True)

Do While filename <> ""

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)

    With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        For j = 2 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
            If .Cells(j, 1) <> "" Then
                x = x + 1
                ReDim Preserve varArray(1 To UBound(varArray, 1), 1 To x)
                    For k = 1 To UBound(varArray, 1)
                        varArray(k, x) = .Cells(j, k)
                    Next
            End If
        Next


    End With
    wb.Close
filename = Dir
Loop

    ReDim varArray2(1 To UBound(varArray, 2), 1 To UBound(varArray, 1))

    With Workbooks("Retail_Goal_Report.xlsm").Worksheets("Merged Reports")

        For j = 1 To UBound(varArray, 2)
            For k = 1 To UBound(varArray, 1)
                varArray2(j, k) = varArray(k, j)
            Next
        Next

        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(UBound(varArray, 2), UBound(varArray, 1))) = varArray2
    End With

myFolder = "C:\Retail-Goal\merge\"
myvar = FileList(myFolder, "*.xlsx")
For i = LBound(myvar) To UBound(myvar)
    Kill myFolder & myvar(i)
Next

Call Ludicrous(False)


End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't this basically the same question as [your last one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54408729/4088852)?

Comment: @Comintern no, because this is omittimg part of an array that's pulling into an overarching array. The last question was a whole set of data not being saved as a copy of the template, this question is different

Comment: @Comintern and this script has a completely different use-case, this is combining files, not distributing them

Comment: Have you checked to see if the underlying issue is the same? I.e., they are both off by one errors, they are both effecting the last item in the array, they both involve printing, etc.

Comment: @Comintern the only thing I've noticed is that I do not get an issue when I have the array printed into the first row `.Range(.Cells(1,1)`  but I don't know why that is. 
instead of this line: `.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(UBound(varArray, 2), UBound(varArray, 1))) = varArray2`

Comment: You just answered your own question.  If the end of the `Range` is row `UBound(varArray, 2)` when you start at row 1, you can't use the same ending row when you start at row 2.

Comment: @Comintern I understand that my revision says: `varArray2 = A1 to rows.count to columns.count` but why doesn't it offset it when I change `.Cells(1,1)` to `.Cells(2,1)` and forego the last row being omitted?

Comment: `.Cells(2, 1)` is the start of the `Range` you're writing to. `.Cells(UBound(varArray, 2), UBound(varArray, 1))` is the end of the `Range` you're writing to.  If you change the start without changing the end by the same amount, it gets smaller.

Comment: I figured both Bound statements just described the dimensions of the array, why would the destination cell for the array to print matter? What would you suggest I change? I’m just confused, my apologies if this is redundant

Comment: @Peter _some_ vba arrays are 0 based.  Actually vba arrays can be _any_ base, not just 0 or 1.  The OP has all 1 based arrays.

Comment: @nick Comintern has given you the answer.  When you code `.Range(CellA, CellB) = SomeArray` if the specified range is smaller than the array, the array is truncated to fit in the specified range.  To get the whole array you need to ensure the range size equals the array size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Nick Landa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10414376/nick-lanta) submitted,

`.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(UBound(varArray, 2), UBound(varArray, 1))) = varArray2`

Should be

`.Range(.Cells(2, 1), 1 + .Cells(UBound(varArray, 2), UBound(varArray, 1))) = varArray2`

Your array is 148 row. If you do not select a 148 rows range, you will only output what is selected and trunk everything else. In this case, it was 147 rows, since you started at row #2 and you are going up to row #148.

Side notes : A better way of doing it would be to rename your iteration variables (instead of having `i` and `j`) to use RowIterator and ColumnIterator, this way you understand much better was is going on.

Then finally to optimize the speed of your code instead of transposing your matrix in a dedicated step, then sending the value to the sheet, you should just send the value to the sheet in a dedicated instruction.

```
For RowIterator = 1 To UBound(varArray, 2)
    For ColumnIterator = 1 To UBound(varArray, 1)
        .Cells(1 + RowIterator, ColumnIterator) = varArray(ColumnIterator, RowIterator)
    Next
 Next
```

Since this way doesn't involve selecting a range then copying the array in it, you wouldn't have run into this issue.